# Xamarin Forms 4.2.0 Tabbed Page tab text color no longer works

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

If you look here you can see the normal Xamarin Forms tabbed page.  The text color of the tabs itself looks like a light gray.  If anything its not white.  I upgraded to Xamarin 4.2.0 Visual Studio 16.3.2 and all of a sudden the text color of the tabs is white.  Nothing in my code changed.  How do I get it 
back?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/tabbed-page

Update:
I posted a bug 
[here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/8069)

Edit: here's an example project with the issue

https://github.com/attrib75/XamIoSSearchBarColorBug

Comment: Just to be sure, the background color of the tabs is still the same which means that now the white text is really hard to see?

Comment: Yes, it appears nothing has changed except for the text is now white

Comment: I looked into the source code of that release and don't see anything obvious which would make the text go white. Anyway, I have a workaround for you which should remedy the issue.

Comment: @PatrickGoode Hi , have you solved it , which type of device tested ,iOS or Android .

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFTI Hi, I have not solved it.  This is for both Android and IOS Samsung 9, I phone 6, any Andrdoid or IOS emulator.  thanks

Comment: @PatrickGoode Okey , it's strange . If not resetting manually, will not change .

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT I'm sorry, what do you mean?  What can I do ?

Comment: @PatrickGoode Hi, sorry for meaning it maybe an issue when version updated. Have seen submitted in GitHub , let's follow it up in GitHub . Hope there will be good workarounds or explains .

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT sounds good thank you!

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT is it better to file a bug with micorosft support? Thanks

Comment: @PatrickGoode Yeah , it's better .But before submitting it , you also can have a try with current latest version of Xamarin Forms (4.3.0.947036) .